# Can the Silverstripe admin interface have Step-by-Step functionality?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

We have a project on Silverstripe which has some well defined processes for the `/admin/` section:

1. Do a thing
2. Then do another thing
3. Then do a third thing

I was wondering if there's existing functionality in Silverstripe (or a module) that enables this sort of behaviour in the `/admin/` section?

`ModelAdmin` automatically generates an interface for editing/ managing models - but in this case we need to guide the site administrators through the 1-2-3 process, which involves a number of different models.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: you can try and make a tabs for steps the admins need to follow

Comment: Maybe https://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/silverstripe/multiform can help you? Never used it, but it's meant for building stepped forms, at least for frontend.

If you do the things on one dataobject, you can check if the first thing was done and then provide the fields for the next step.